# Long AWS Lambda request exits with read Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
      clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
        .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
        .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.none())
        .build()

      asyncClient: LambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
        .region(region)
        .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
        .build()
```

This is how I'm creating the LambdaClient.
The task on Lambda can run for ~10mins. I know that Lambda is not suited for such long tasks.

Even after setting the apiCallTimeout to 20 mins the call still fails after ~2mins with
`software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.sdkclientexception: unable to execute http request: read timed out`.

I'm using [Java SDK2](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/overview-summary.html) and can't find any other setting to increase the timeout.
I saw [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/321#issuecomment-304491455) but can't find ClientConfiguration in Java2 SDK.

Comment: The maximum timeout that you can set for Lambda is 15 minutes, so you shouldn't have problem in 10 minutes task

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the timeout for the socket.

```
  clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
    .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
    .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
    .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.none())
    .build()

  httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder()
    .socketTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
    .build()

  asyncClient: LambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()
    .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
    .region(region)
    .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
    .httpClient(httpClient)
    .build()
```

You can get more information on configuring HTTP on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration.html